# Search for components in React Devtools profiler?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

Is there any search functionality in the React Devtools Profiler (FlameGraph or Ranked view) that I missed? I want to see how much time my new component `MyGreatComponent` took for rendering, but it's "hidden" between all the other components and not easy to find.

Comment: i don't think there is a way. Maybe download the profile data and review that?